# How to get the time series of colored noise obtained by AudioGenerator function?

Tags: random, time-series, sound

In the documentation I found a code that plots a Periodogram.

```
noises = {"White", "PeriodicRandomNoise", "Pink", "Brown", "Blue"};
Periodogram[AudioGenerator /@ noises, 2000, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "dB"}]
```

[image]

How can I get a text file that will contain the time series for which the graph is plotted?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to extract the values from the plot

```
pg = Periodogram[AudioGenerator /@ noises, 2000, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log10", "dB"}];
points = Cases[pg, Line[x__] -> x, ∞];
```

Verify

```
ListLinePlot[points, PlotRange -> All]
```

You can export each element of `points` to a separate file

```
MapThread[Export[#1 <> ".csv", #2] &, {noises, points}]
```